# ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to select a row in mysql where my variable req.body.email is found in the column Email_Address
this is my code snippet

app.post('/login', function(req, res){

```
con.query("select * from people where Email_address= "+ req.body.email, (err, res) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log('the email '+ req.body.email +'does not exist in the database');
        throw err;
    }
    else{
        console.log('selected');
        if(password == req.body.password)
            //res.redirect('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' });
            res.send('hello');   
    }



});
```

but I am getting an error below

**Error:**`ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1`

Any Ideas on how to solve it

Comment: found it by adding :  var queryy = "select * from people where Email_address=? ";
    con.query( queryy,[req.body.email], (err, res) => {...}

Answer (score 1):

You need add `'` to the email parameter,change

```
con.query("select * from people where Email_address= "+ req.body.email
```

to

```
con.query("select * from people where Email_address= '"+ req.body.email +"'"
```